# Objective-C with C++ Member Initialization

Tags: c++, objective-c, constructor, objective-c++

I have a C++ object declared in my Objective-C class.

The C++ object has only one constructor that takes several parameters.

In C++ code I would parse the parameters to the constructor in the initializer list of the class that contains it.

How do I do the same in Objective-C?

When I compile I get an error telling me that there is no appropriate default constructor for my C++ object, as you would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are able to do something like that in Objective-C, because there are no constructors and initializer lists there. But you can use `std::shared_ptr` or other smart pointer to store a pointer to your class and create the object itself in `init` method

Answer (score 0):

You could change the object to a (smart) pointer for this object type. Then you can delay the construction of the object to the moment you see fit.